# How do I remove the Accessibility options/icon from the login screen?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, login-screen, accessibility

Have young kids that manage to foul up Ubuntu by playing with the universal access options at the login screen. Tried following the directions for 10.04 but the stated directories don't exist in 12.04 How can I completely remove the Universal Access options from the login screen from Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: The default settings file (located at: **/usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz**) does **not** appear to have any settings related to **Universal Access**.  Nor does the command line tool (by running: **/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --help**).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the accessibility option in the login menu bar is hard-coded into the `unity-greeter` source code, and short of modifying that, there appears to be no way to *remove* it (like a number of other Unity UI features...)

Your best bet is to simply make the icon *invisible*. While it will still be there, it won't show and hopefully your children will be fooled :)

- The icon is provided by the file `/usr/share/unity-greeter/a11y.svg`
- Here's the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/h2dRGH4K) of an appropriate blank icon.
- To replace yours, open a terminal and:

  ```
  cd /usr/share/unity-greeter
  sudo mv a11y.svg _a11y_backup.svg
  sudo wget -Oa11y.svg http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=h2dRGH4K
  ```

Result of clicking the "invisible" icon:

[image]

Comment: That worked. The icon is "hidden". We'll see if that is sufficient to keep the little ones from destroying the usefulness of Ubuntu 12.04...

Comment: @CharlesHartman: glad to know, hope it works out too. Please consider accepting the answer (tick/check mark on the left) in that case, so that the question is closed and people know this "hack" works.

Comment: Having spent some time looking at the greeter source code over the past month, I think this is the cleanest solution short of a recompile.

Comment: Is this hard-coding problem still the case for Ubuntu 16.10?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented solution from 11.10 and it works for me :)

askubuntu.com/questions/113514/how-can-i-remove-icons-from-the-gnome-shell-panel

Yo open mentioned file with owner privileges I used command in terminal:

```
gksudo gnome-open /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js
```